# Wrap <a></a> when @ is pressed - Jquery

Tags: jquery, keypress

Here's what i got -:

`<div contenteditable="true">Hey man @tt</div>`

Now I would like to wrap `<a></a>` around when ever `@` is entered in it.

For eg when `@` is pressed, html would be

`<div contenteditable="true">Hey man <a>@</a>tt</div>`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: @rahularyansharma Despite its name, `.wrap()` won't help here.

Comment: Does nothing useful to wrap just the `@`...

Comment: your question is either about wrapping or keypress. which one?

Comment: @slash197 Why can't it be both?

Comment: @VisioN it can, I just wanted to know what kind of answer is he expecting

Answer (score 0):

use `replace()`.

try this

```
var output= $('div').html().replace('@','<a>@</a>');
$('div').html(output);
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/SJJq8/2/)

Comment: @rahularyansharma. `@` pressed inside a div? the question is vague and the answer is good and helpful. +1.

Comment: i was about to write that ...key pressed inside a div? :)..thanks @gdoron

Comment: It's a [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_Editable) div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keypress(function(e){
    if ((e.shiftKey == true) && (e.charCode == 64))
    {
        $(this).html().replace('@','<a>@</a>');
    }
});
```